# Как создать таблицу умножения от 1 до 10 через stream

Tags: java, алгоритм, циклы, потоки-данных, java-stream

У меня есть два метода. Первый метод выводит таблицу умножения от 1 до 10 в один столбец, а второй в 5 столбцов. Могу ли я вместо этих циклов задействовать **stream**(только начал его изучать) ? Если да, то как ?

```
public static void multiplicationTableInOneColumn() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            System.out.println(i + " x " + j + " = " + i * j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

```
public static void multiplicationTableInFiveColumn() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + " x " + i + " = " + (i * j) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i ++) {
        for (int j = 6; j <= 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + " x " + i + " = " + (i * j) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да конечно можете
Вот небольшой пример

```
IntStream.range(1, 11).forEach(i->{
  IntStream.range(1, 11).forEach(j->{System.out.println(i + " x " + j + " = " + i * j);});
  System.out.println();
});
```

И

```
IntStream.range(1, 11).forEach(i->{
  IntStream.range(1, 6).forEach(j->{
    System.out.print(j + " x " + i + " = " + (i * j) + "\t");
  });
  System.out.println();

  IntStream.range(6, 11).forEach(j->{
    System.out.print(j + " x " + i + " = " + (i * j) + "\t");
  });
  System.out.println();
});
```

Comment: А как мне вывести в 5 столбцов ? В 1 столбец отлично выводит, но мне так же надо и в 5.

Comment: Обновил ответ посмотрите

Comment: Да, это работает. Но код получается по размерности одинаковый. Подскажите, есть ли смысл использовать stream для таких задач или лучше через for ? Есть ли существенная разница в производительности ?

Comment: @Tokamo при построении таблицы из 100 элементов разницы в производительности нет никакой. Что for, что stream выполнятся так быстро, что вы не замените разницу как не старайтесь. Тут, скорее всего, больше всего времени съест `System.out.print`.

Comment: Опубликуйте вопрос если вам это действительно важно